# Acer Laptop Windows 7 Full drive windows shutdown, CHKDSC stalls 55%

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Our laptop started warning of low disc, and has been running slow. Used CCleaner, but only recovered 2GB. Windows has spontaneously shutdown and on restart, CHKDSC stalled out at 55%. Ran Malwarebytes and it gets almost completed and windows has to shutdown. And we are back to square one. We have deleted all games and most videos and programs that we don't need, but the 200 gb drive c: has 5 GB free of 88 GB and DATA D: has 20 GB free of 84 GB. I'm not very computer savy, Is there any easy way to fix this? We have not been able to run any optimization or defrag for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

Both CCleaner and Windows "Disk Cleanup" have the ability to delete all restore points but the last one. This should free up another few Gigs if you haven't done this already. Also, make sure you're not using too much drive space for system restore points. You can check and modify this in "System settings \ System protection. (recommended is 10-12% of your disk).

Also, you can use a great little freebee software called "Folder Size" which will show you what folders are taking up the most space on your drive. Be careful when deleting folders and files from the C drive as you can corrupt your system - if you don't know what it is, ask or leave it alone. Here's the link:  http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks Zvi, I had already ran CCleaner and successfully completed all five stages of CHKDSK. Still only have about 3.7 GB free on drive C. Check my seeting on system protection, its at the minimum setting with current usage at 155.38 MB. I'll look at the foldersize link and see what I can do.     Dave

Comment: That's your best bet. You can also go into your "uninstall software" window and sort by size to see of there is any software you don't need that's taking up lots of space.

Comment: Zvi, thanks again. One thing I'm not clear on is the DATA D: drive. I guess the 200 GB drive has been partitioned in half. About 5 years ago I upgraded from Vista to Windows 7. Is it possible that the space on this drive is the old Vista?

Comment: Yes. If you see a folder like Windows.old - that's it. Don't need it.